# Flutter go_router throws error unknown route name: /auth/:uid with '_nameToPath.containsKey(name)'

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod, gorouter

In my flutter app I am building routes with go_router and flutter_riverpod but as I have setup my routes with provider I started getting this error

```
The following assertion was thrown building
DefaultSelectionStyle:
unknown route name: /auth/:uid
'package:go_router/src/configuration.dart':
Failed assertion: line 243 pos 12:
'_nameToPath.containsKey(name)'
```

Here is my main.dart file where I am calling routes.

```
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp])
      .then((_) async {
    await Firebase.initializeApp();
    await FirebaseAppCheck.instance
        .activate(androidProvider: AndroidProvider.playIntegrity);

    runApp(
      const ProviderScope(
        child: MyApp(),
      ),
    );
  });
  FlutterError.demangleStackTrace = (StackTrace stack) {
    if (stack is stack_trace.Trace) return stack.vmTrace;
    if (stack is stack_trace.Chain) return stack.toTrace().vmTrace;
    return stack;
  };
}

class MyApp extends ConsumerWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    return MaterialApp.router(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'DiscountLo',
      theme: AppTheme.theme,
      locale: ref.watch(languageNotifierProvider),
      localizationsDelegates: {
        AppLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate
      },
      supportedLocales: [Locale("en"), Locale("hi")],
      routerDelegate:  ref.watch(routeProvider).routerDelegate,
      routeInformationParser:  ref.watch(routeProvider).routeInformationParser,
      routeInformationProvider:  ref.watch(routeProvider).routeInformationProvider,
    );
  }
}
```

my router.dart file where I have created a provider and I am trying to call redirect to handle state management and protect routes.

```
final routeProvider = Provider<GoRouter>(
  (ref) {
    return GoRouter(
      routes: [
        GoRoute(
          name: "home",
          path: RouteNameConstants.home,
          pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) =>
              MaterialPage(
            child: const HomeView(),
          ),
        ),
        GoRoute(
          name: "splash",
          path: RouteNameConstants.splash,
          pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) =>
              MaterialPage(
            child: const SplashScreen(),
          ),
        ),
        GoRoute(
          name: "onboard",
          path: RouteNameConstants.onboarding,
          pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) =>
              MaterialPage(
            child: const OnboardingView(),
          ),
        ),
        GoRoute(
          name: "error",
          path: RouteNameConstants.error,
          pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) =>
              MaterialPage(
            child: ErrorPage(text: state.pathParameters['text']!),
          ),
        ),
        GoRoute(
          name: "auth",
          path: RouteNameConstants.authState,
          pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
            return MaterialPage(
              child: AuthChanges(uid: state.pathParameters['uid']!),
            );
          },
        ),
        GoRoute(
          name: "filter",
          path: RouteNameConstants.filter,
          pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
            return MaterialPage(
              child: FilterView(
                index: double.tryParse(state.pathParameters['index']!)!.toInt(),
                category: state.pathParameters['category']!,
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ],
      redirect: (context, state) {
        final loginState = ref.watch(authStateChangeProvider);
        if (loginState.isLoading) {
          return RouteNameConstants.splash;
        } else if (loginState.hasError) {
          return state.namedLocation(
            RouteNameConstants.error,
            pathParameters: {
              "text": loginState.error.toString(),
            },
          );
        } else if (loginState.value != null) {
          return state.namedLocation(RouteNameConstants.authState,
              pathParameters: {"uid": loginState.value!.uid});
        } else {
          return RouteNameConstants.onboarding;
        }
      },
    );
  },
);
```

my routers path name constants

```
class RouteNameConstants {
  static const String home = '/';
  static const String splash = '/splash';
  static const String onboarding = '/onboarding';
  static const String authState = '/auth/:uid';
  static const String error = '/error/:text';
  static const String filter = '/filter';
}
```

please if anyone can help me

Comment: Are you getting route paths and route names mixed up somewhere?

Comment: not at all, even just for hit and run I even make route names and path same

Comment: When you are defining the Routes, you use RouteNameConstants for all the paths.  I'd suggest renaming that class as RoutePathConstants. The error message says "Unknown route name" and then it lists one of your paths. Route names and Route paths can't be used interchangeably.

Comment: thanks I changed it and solved my bug

Comment: Awesome.  Congrats.  Maybe you should post what you were doing wrong as an answer to your own question.

Comment: hey you helped me,
can you answer this question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76840124/go-router-navigation-is-not-working-with-no-errors

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254813/discussion-between-abhi-jain-and-john-weidner).

Answer (score 0):

I was using

```
class RouteNameConstants {
  static const String home = 'home';
  static const String splash = 'splash';
  static const String onboarding = 'onboard';
  static const String authState = 'auth';
  static const String error = 'error';
  static const String filter = 'filter';
  static const String profile = 'profile';
  static const String phone = 'phone';
  static const String otp = 'otp';
  static const String profilecontent = 'profilecontent';
}
```

as path in GoRoute instead now I use as name and defined path this way solves my problem

```
import 'package:discountlo/core/route_constant.dart';
import 'package:discountlo/features/auth/views/otp_view.dart';
import 'package:discountlo/features/auth/views/phone_view.dart';
import 'package:discountlo/features/home/view/filter_view.dart';
import 'package:discountlo/features/home/view/profile_content_view.dart';
import 'package:discountlo/features/home/view/profile_view.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';
import 'package:discountlo/features/auth/views/onboarding_screen.dart';
import 'package:discountlo/features/auth/views/splash_view.dart';
import 'package:discountlo/features/home/view/home_view.dart';
import 'auth_changes.dart';
import 'error_page.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'features/auth/controller/auth_controller.dart';

final _key = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

final routeProvider = Provider<GoRouter>(
  (ref) {
    return GoRouter(
      navigatorKey: _key,
      debugLogDiagnostics: true,
      routes: [
        GoRoute(
          name: RouteNameConstants.home,
          path: "/",
          pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) =>
              MaterialPage(
            child: const HomeView(),
          ),
        ),
        GoRoute(
          path: "/splash",
          name: RouteNameConstants.splash,
          pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) =>
              MaterialPage(
            child: const SplashScreen(),
          ),
        ),
        GoRoute(
          path: "/otp",
          name: RouteNameConstants.otp,
          pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) =>
              MaterialPage(
            child: OTPView(
              phoneNumber: state.pathParameters['phoneNumber']!,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        GoRoute(
          path: "/phone",
          name: RouteNameConstants.phone,
          pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) =>
              MaterialPage(
            child: const PhoneView(),
          ),
        ),
        GoRoute(
          path: "/profile",
          name: RouteNameConstants.profile,
          pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) =>
              MaterialPage(
            child: const ProfileView(),
          ),
        ),
        GoRoute(
          path: "/profilecontent",
          name: RouteNameConstants.profilecontent,
          pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) =>
              MaterialPage(
            child: ProfileContentView(
              clicked: state.pathParameters['clicked']!,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        GoRoute(
          path: "/onboard",
          name: RouteNameConstants.onboarding,
          pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) =>
              MaterialPage(
            child: const OnboardingView(),
          ),
        ),
        GoRoute(
          path: "/error/:text",
          name: RouteNameConstants.error,
          pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) =>
              MaterialPage(
            child: ErrorPage(text: state.pathParameters['text']!),
          ),
        ),
        GoRoute(
          path: "/auth/:uid",
          name: RouteNameConstants.authState,
          pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
            return MaterialPage(
              child: AuthChanges(uid: state.pathParameters['uid']!),
            );
          },
        ),
        GoRoute(
          path: "/filter/:index/:category",
          name: RouteNameConstants.filter,
          pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
            debugPrint("sdvf ${state.pathParameters}");
            return MaterialPage(
              child: FilterView(
                index: double.tryParse(state.pathParameters['index']!)!.toInt(),
                category: state.pathParameters['category']!,
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ],
      redirect: (context, state) {
        final loginState = ref.watch(authStateChangeProvider);
        if (loginState.isLoading) {
          return state.namedLocation(RouteNameConstants.splash);
        } else if (loginState.hasError) {
          return state.namedLocation(
            RouteNameConstants.error,
            pathParameters: {
              "text": loginState.error.toString(),
            },
          );
        } else if (loginState.value != null) {
          return state.namedLocation(RouteNameConstants.authState,
              pathParameters: {"uid": loginState.value!.uid});
        } else {
          return state.namedLocation(RouteNameConstants.onboarding);
        }
      },
    );
  },
);
```